# MS-Access Form Combo box can't limit pasted records

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

We have an Access database to track work requests. We have a form where we enter the info for the requests. We wish to limit the departments which can be entered to a list, which we have entered in a Table called Departments.

The Departments control on our work request entry form is a combo box based on the Departments table. This works for limiting the departments entered by hand; however, jobs are often entered by copying and pasting old info as a whole record, and changing any information as necessary. When this occurs, the Department control is not limited by the combo box.

I need a method to validate the data entered in the Department control on the form against the entries in the Department field before the record is saved to the table. If the Department from the pasted entry does not match any of the records in the Departments table, I would like it to throw a message box.

I have attempted to use the BeforeUpdate event procedure, but can't figure out how to evaluate the current Department entry in my form against the entries in my Departments table. Can anyone suggest how to create this validation?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
Dim strSQL As String
Dim RS  As DAO.Recordset
strSQL = "select * from Table1 where (Flda) = '" & Me.txtFldA & "';"
Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
If RS.EOF Then
    MsgBox "Not a valid Department", vbOKOnly, "Incorrect Department Entered"
End If
RS.Close
Set RS = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running Access 2010 you could enforce the validation at the table level by using a `Before Change` data macro like this:

[image: BeforeChange.png]

For more information, see

[Create a data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx)

Comment: @SMartin You can download a working example [here](http://wikisend.com/download/120420/Validation.zip).

Comment: Found another way of handling it at the form level with DLookup, but cant post the answer yet; this is helpful though, I'm going to check it out in the future. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is set up a relationship between your Departments field and the corresponding field in the Departments database.  Enforce Referrential Integrity (without cascading), and this should prevent anyone from adding a record in your Work Requests table where the department doesn't exist in your Departments table.